# How do I toggle screen geometry with hotkeys?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, display, monitor, external-monitor

My main computer is a laptop with an external monitor and I need set up hotkeys to switch between two display modes:

- external monitor only (1920*1080)
- internal + external monitor (1280*800 + 1920*1080) (not mirror mode)

Fn+F7 does similar things for me, but it toggles between

- internal only
- internal + external (mirror mode)
- external only

I'd rather add dedicated hotkeys for two of themodes I need. How do I do it?

My system is Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on [ThinkPad X200](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-73156).